Can't do 'dbus-send' from shutdown script, but it works fine at CLI
For some reason my xfce4 refuses to remember my session when I shut down or restart (the correct box is ticked in the 'session and startup' dialogue).  The good folks on the xfce forum can't replicate it or fix it. However they did come up with this script which works fine if I execute it at a terminal:
% dbus-send --session --dest=org.xfce.SessionManager --print-reply /org/xfce/SessionManager org.xfce.Session.Manager.Checkpoint string:""

... but trying to automate that, I created a .service according to the systemd rules:
contents of: '/etc/systemd/system/rays-shutdown.service':
[Unit]
Description=Save xfce session
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/save-xfce
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target


Contents of: '/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/save-xfce':
dbus-send --session --dest=org.xfce.SessionManager --print-reply /org/xfce/SessionManager org.xfce.Session.Manager.Checkpoint string:""

... it all seems proper, however:
% systemctl enable rays-shutdown.service --now

... gives me an error
% systemctl status rays-shutdown.service

... reports:
...
save-xfce[2442]: Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
...

So, is there anything I can do to resolve that error?  Strange that it works fine as a CLI script, but it throws the error in a '.service'.
BTW I also tried it with scripts in '/etc/rc0.d' and '/etc/rc6.d' but they seem to be ignored entirely.

How is xfce4 started? I don't know how it would work when started by a display manager, but if you use startxfce4, everything would just be running in a session scope unit. There are probably no reliable way to leverage systemd dependency to make sure something is ran before session scope unit(s) get terminated. So I think not even user service would be the way to go. You should probably see if xfce4 has support for "pre-down scripts" instead. (In case you are still not aware, you need that command run way before system shutdown procedures begin.)

I don't think xfce4 even leverages any part of systemd to get itself "indirectly" terminated in any case. On the other hand, one way I can think of is, you can have a wrapper (in e.g. /usr/local/bin/) for xfce4-session-logout. I don't know if its GUI leverages the executable though (and if so, would it take PATH into consideration).

Or maybe you can have the command run as soon as the xfce4 session is started? (With xdg autostart maybe? Probably too early with xinitrc.d.)

Your comments just go to show how overly complex all this stuff is. If it can be done I"ll be taking any answers verbatim and on faith -- I doubt I'll ever understand this stuff.

I don't think dbus --session works outside of a session.   Try dbus --address unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus --session...

It does seem that the command above only works before the session quits.  I want to see what Tom has to say about his idea first, then I'll try yours, tx.

Here's an untested answer for you. Create a shell script called xfce4-session-logout in /usr/local/bin/ with the following content:
#!/bin/sh
dbus-send --session --dest=org.xfce.SessionManager --print-reply /org/xfce/SessionManager org.xfce.Session.Manager.Checkpoint string:""
exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout

Make sure it is executable:
% sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session-logout


It doesn't work.  Now here's the funny thing, I can move '/usr/local/bin/xfce4-session-logout' to another directory and it changes nothing!  I can still logout, shutdown or reboot as before.  It seems that command is not being executed!

@RayAndrews Of course. The idea is that, when it is there, it will "override" /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout if the relevant PATH environment has /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin. If you want to try to get this work, you may want to try it in your terminal first. First of all, check what's the output of printenv PATH. If /usr/local/bin isn't even there or ordered before /usr/bin, naturally it wouldn't work at all. If it is, you may then want to check type xfce4-session-logout (or which).

@RayAndrews If so, you may then want to see if running xfce4-session-logout in a shell works. (It seems that it should bring up the shutdown popup/menu, but again I haven't really tested.)

I understand the override idea, but your command goes on to call the 'real' command and as I said, even when I move the real command, nothing changes.  I moved the command to another disk and nothing changes.  I tried ticking 'Prompt on Logout' in 'Session and Startup' and that also changes nothing.  I am not prompted.

@RayAndrews Oh so that was a typo? You said move '/usr/local/bin/xfce4-session-logout', not /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout.

Ok, I can call it from a terminal and it works fine.  So that's the proof -- when I try to shutdown or restart normally the command '/usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout' (original) is simply not being executed.

... it's not that it doesn't work, it's that it's not being called.  Why not?

@RayAndrews I think/guess if you use the "Log Out" item in the Application Menu, xfce4-session-logout would be called. But if you use some button somewhere else, it would probably not be called. The thing is, xfce4-session-logout itself is just a little program that talks to the xfce session manager via dbus (like ask it to show the popup/menu). There can be other things like "button on a panel" that is more or less a "repeated implementation" of the same thing.

@RayAndrews Namely xfce4-panel has something called "action buttons" (I don't know what they are exactly; maybe some "exit" button / menu "on the right"?), which I can see in the code that some "Log out" is one of them and they do not make use of the program but instead leverages dbus themselves like the program: https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-panel/blob/xfce4-panel-4.18.6/plugins/actions/actions.c#L892 https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-session/blob/master/xfce4-session-logout/main.c#L214
